# How to validate number only textbox in SmartGWT?

Tags: validation, handler, smartgwt

Textbox should accept only numbers, I would like to use anyother Handlers other than `ChangedHandler/ Changehandler/ KeyPressHandler`

My Validation class,

```
public class UnderLyingIDChangeHandler implements ChangedHandler {
    private final CreditRiskView creditRiskView;

    public UnderLyingIDChangeHandler(CreditRiskView creditRiskView) {
        this.creditRiskView = creditRiskView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ChangedEvent event) {
        String value= (String) event.getItem().getValue();
        if(!value.matches("[0-9]*")){
            creditRiskView.invalidUnderlyingID();
        }
}
```

This is the main class where I need to show the validation

```
public class CreditRiskView{
private TextItem underlyingIDField;
public void addunderlyingIDInputChangeHadler(ChangedHandler changedHandler) {

    //logic is that this method will invoked in the UnderLyingIDChangeHandler class

     underlyingIDField.addChangedHandler(changedHandler);
    }
 public void invalidUnderlyingID(){

    // I don't know how to set an error message as underlyingIDField.clearValue() 
       method is not doing well.

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the textbox is a **TextItem** in a **DynamicForm** it works like this:

```
IsIntegerValidator isIntegerValidator = new IsIntegerValidator();
isIntegerValidator.setErrorMessage("error message");
textItem.setValidators(isIntegerValidator);
```

And to show the errors like that when you call the **form.validate()** you need to set the *setShowInlineErrors(true)* in the form.

Answer (score 0):

What about limiting characters that can be entered by the user?
Please see this sample:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#form_keypress_filter

Comment: but my use case is, the user can enter any value and need to validate that example like [link] (https://www.google.co.in/search?q=validation+example+images&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=663&tbm=isch&imgil=5-NnMuVG8GyU-M%253A%253BwYih5EUmz9nrkM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fdzineblog.com%25252F18-impressive-web-form-validation-scripts-to-enhance-user-experience%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=5-NnMuVG8GyU-M%253A%252CwYih5EUmz9nrkM%252C_&usg=__msnZlG6RD45XOPMEIe9Kq9WkLuI%3D&ved=0ahUKEwij5_fYhejLAhUPco4KHZ7rA9AQyjcILg&ei=UJX7VqP_J4_kuQSe14-ADQ#imgrc=5-NnMuVG8GyU-M%3A)